# Background image is compressed in nexus 5 android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, splash-screen

I have an image for splash screen of size equals to Nexus-5 dimension (1080 x 1920 pixels). 
Now When I add this image in background of LinearLayout, it seems to be compressed, here is the code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/app_bg"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

           <!-- 
              <ImageView android:id="@+id/splash_screen" 
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:background="@drawable/app_bg"
               android:layout_gravity="center"/>
           -->

     </LinearLayout>
```

Real image is

[image]

and attached is the screen shot from nexus-5

[image]

Comment: You have on screen buttons and bars... use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` for your **ImageView** `src`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setting the image as background you show, you should use image view as below, and use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` and frame layout is best for this purpose.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop">
</ImageView>
```

Thanks